# What's the purpose of this SQL Statement?

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT * 

FROM 
    daaddress ad, 
    (daname nam LEFT OUTER JOIN daenttonam etn on nam.entity_id = etn.entity_id)
```

I don't understand what the two "tables" seperated by a comma with no JOIN statement is supposed to do. Is it a FULL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It outputs the cartesian product between `daadress` and a `LEFT JOIN` of `daname` and `daenttonam`.

Using `JOIN` syntax, it can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM   daaddress ad
CROSS JOIN
(
       daname nam
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       daenttonam etn
ON     nam.entity_id = etn.entity_id
)
```

The parens may be omitted:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM   daaddress ad
CROSS JOIN
       daname nam
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       daenttonam etn
ON     nam.entity_id = etn.entity_id
```

It's hard to tell its purpose not being aware of the model specifics.